# Datepicker displayed on top of the modal

Tags: ionic2, ionic-native, ionic2-datetime

In my ionic 2 application, we are have a page which shows date picker on click of a button. When date picker is displayed, if app goes in background, we are displaying a lock screen modal. The problem is when we show the modal, the date picker is displaying on top of the modal. Does anyone have an idea about how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You may probably need to adjust z-index property of the datepicker within the stylesheet (decrease the value, so it is less than the one for modal), so it will not be rendered on top of the modal.

Comment: Already our modal has displayed in full screen. So datepicker is lesser size here.

Comment: Just to make sure, I understood correctly the issue, which you're trying to address. Z-index is not about size, it's rather about which elements are on "top" layer and which are rendered underneath. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index